# What's the difference between scalbn and ldexp

Tags: c++, c, function, math, c99

The C99 standard defines `ldexp(double a, int exp)` as *a × 2<sup>exp</sup>* and `scalbn(double a, int exp)` as *a × FLT_RADIX<sup>exp</sup>*

What's the difference between the two if I'm using IEEE-754 arithmetic (i.e. FLT_RADIX == 2)?

Comment: For `FLT_RADIX == 2` they are simply the same.

Comment: @Sven Marnach : May as well put that in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appendix F:

```
        F.9.3.6  The ldexp functions

       [#1] On a binary system, ldexp(x, exp) is equivalent to

               scalbn(x, exp)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference when FLT_RADIX == 2.